# R: Reading a delimited table when end of each row is not delimited

Tags: r, database, text

I am trying to read in the [Census' Geographic Boundary Change Notes](https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/bndrychange/changenotedisplay.php). As one can see at the hyperlink, the file is a K x 11 table. A [pipe-delimited text version](https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/bndrychange/united%20states.txt) is available via the link on that page.

I tried manually saving the pipe-deliminated text version as a .txt file (e.g. foo.txt) and then reading it in as a pipe-deliminated table via:

```
data <- read.table("foo.txt", sep="|")
```

However, this produces an error:

> Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
>     line 177 did not have 11 elements

When I scrolled down to what I think is line 177, I do not see anything missing. I therefore looked at the raw text to see potential issues and one issue is that it looks like the pipes do not delimit individual rows - i.e. there is not any indicator that we are at the end of the row of the table in the raw .txt file. However, this seems to contradict the fact that read.table() was expecting 11 objects.

1. Do I need to add to the .txt file a delimiter corresponding to the end of each row of the table?
2. If so, how might I do this without manually adding a delimiter?

Apologies if this is not the problem.

Comment: The rows are delimited by line breaks - `\n` - you do not need a delimiter at the end of each row.

Comment: I can confirm I get the same error. Line 177 doesn't seem to be problematic and has 11 elements as far as I can tell. You can fudge something together by using `readLines` and then `strsplit`ing each component. Not sure what's gone wrong though.

Comment: It's clunky, but it will give you something to work with - `do.call(rbind, strsplit(readLines("https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/bndrychange/united%20states.txt"),"|",fixed=TRUE))`

Comment: I am not sure how to correctly close out this question since the question is not valid given that the delimiter is not an issue. I have contacted the Census Bureau to fix this problem. The best solution short of lots of string manipulation is thelatemail's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no issue with delimiting. I instead downloaded the .txt file and opened it in Microsoft Excel using '|' as the delimiter. Scrolling down to rows where there were issues, it appears that Spanish characters were causing issues.

Answer (score 1):

Line 177 refers to `Clark's Point city`. Since the default quote argument for `read.table` is `quote = "\"'"` the `'` in `Clark's` is read as the start of a character string. Everything after the `'`, including line breaks, is read as part of one character string until `read.table` gets to line 337, where it finds `Changed to Tohono O'odham Nation` and reads the `'` in `O'odham` as the closing quote character for the character string started on line 177.

If you set `read.table("foo.txt", sep="|", quote = NULL)` it should fix the issue.